# Sharing Strings between Angular Components

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to be able to reach out to my Firebase database to get settings that are stored and then set those variables in my AppComponent and then be able to retrieve that string from any other component that that the AppComponent is is imported with.

I have this in my AppComponent (this retrieves the settings and set them individually and as a group. Let's take `company` as the variable we are trying to share.

```
export class AppComponent {
    public company: string;
    public title: string;
    public version: string;
    public show: boolean = false;
    public settings: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private dropConfig: NgbDropdownConfig, private router: Router, private db: AngularFireDatabase, public authService: AuthService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            if(user) {
                this.authService.findCompany().then((resp) => {
                    this.db.object(resp['company']+'/settings/users/'+user.uid+'/').valueChanges().subscribe((user) => {
                        this.company = resp['company'];
                        dropConfig.placement = 'bottom-right';
                        this.settings = db.object(this.company+'/settings/general').valueChanges();
                        this.settings.subscribe((setting) => {
                            this.title = setting.title;
                            this.version = setting.version;
                            this.show = true;
                        });
                    })
                });
            } else {
                this.show = false;
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

From within my navbar component, just for example, I'm trying to import the AppComponent and then console.log out the company string.

If I place this in my constructor:

```
constructor(public appComp: AppComponent) {
    console.log(this.appComp)
}
```

This is what I get in my console: (in short for sake of simplicity)

```
AppComponent {company: "acme-industries"}
```

Now if I change the console.log to the following:

```
console.log(this.appComp.company)
```

This is what I get in the console.

```
undefined
```

What is the correct way to receive this information? It's available when I leave it at appComp but as soon as I try to get inside the array, it seems like all the information disappears.

**UPDATE**

As per the comments made below, I created a service (to the best of my ability) that places all these settings inside an object and then attempts to return the object. The service is as below.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, delay, map, first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DefaultsService {

    public sets: Observable<any>;
    public settings = {
        "show" : false,
        "company" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "version" : null
    }

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            if(user) {
                this.authService.findCompany().then((resp) => {
                    this.sets = this.db.object(resp["company"]+'/settings/general').valueChanges();
                    this.sets.subscribe((response) => {
                        this.settings.show = true;
                        this.settings.company = resp["company"];
                        this.settings.title = response["title"];
                        this.settings.version = response["version"];
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the update above, here is the `app.component` that would match.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { DefaultsService } from './defaults/defaults.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { NgbDropdownConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { filter, distinctUntilChanged, map, subscribeOn } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, PRIMARY_OUTLET } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title: string;
    version: string;
    show: boolean;

    constructor(private dfServices: DefaultsService, private dropConfig: NgbDropdownConfig, private router: Router, db: AngularFireDatabase, public authService: AuthService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            if(user) {
                console.log(dfServices.settings);
                this.show = dfServices.settings.show;
                this.title = dfServices.settings.title;
                this.version = dfServices.settings.version
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: No, components are not "injectable" and should not be added as an argument to the constructor. You need to build a service instead as suggested by @steveboyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { DefaultsService } from './defaults/defaults.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { NgbDropdownConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { filter, distinctUntilChanged, map, subscribeOn } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, PRIMARY_OUTLET } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    public sets: Observable<any>;

    title: string;
    version: string;
    show: boolean;

    constructor(private dfServices: DefaultsService, private dropConfig: NgbDropdownConfig, 
      private router: Router, db: AngularFireDatabase, public authService: AuthService, 
      private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

        afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
          if(user) {
              this.authService.findCompany().then((resp) => {
                  this.sets = db.object(resp["company"]+'/settings/general').valueChanges();
                  this.sets.subscribe((response) => {
                      dfServices.settings = {
                        "show" : true,
                        "company" : resp["company"],
                        "title" : response["title"],
                        "version" : response["version"]
                    };
                  });
              });
          }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

And your DefaultsService should be

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, delay, map, first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DefaultsService {

    public sets: Observable<any>;
    public settings = {
        "show" : false,
        "company" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "version" : null
    }

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    }

    getSettings() {
      return this.settings;
    }
}
```

Then you can inject `DefaultsService` into your other components and call `getSettings`. Of course, there are other cleaner way to achieve this and I can post a better solution if you wish.

**Update**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, delay, map, first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DefaultsService {

  public sets: Observable<any>;

  private settingsObs = null;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.createSettingsObs();
  }

  getSettings() {
    return this.settingsObs;
  }

  createSettingsObs() {

    this.settingsObs = Observable.create(function (observer) {

      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
          this.authService.findCompany().then((resp) => {
            this.sets = this.db.object(resp["company"] + '/settings/general').valueChanges();
            this.sets.subscribe((response) => {
              const settings = {
                "show": true,
                "company": resp["company"],
                "title": response["title"],
                "version": response["version"]
              };
              observer.next(settings);
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And in any component you should subscribe since you don't know when the call to the sever will actually finishes:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { DefaultsService } from './defaults/defaults.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { NgbDropdownConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { filter, distinctUntilChanged, map, subscribeOn } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, PRIMARY_OUTLET } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public sets: Observable<any>;

  title: string;
  version: string;
  show: boolean;

  constructor(private dfServices: DefaultsService, private dropConfig: NgbDropdownConfig,
    private router: Router, db: AngularFireDatabase, public authService: AuthService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.dfServices.getSettings.subscribe((settings: any)=> {
      console.log(settings);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes it so I have to put the code that I put in `app.component.ts` into every other component that I want to use it in. That completely gets rid of what I'm wanting to do. I want to be able to set the title by just calling `this.title = dfServices.getSettings().title` in every component.

Comment: Actually no you don't have to put the same code you have in `app.component.ts` in every component, in any other component just call `dfServices.getSettings().title` and you should have the title value.

Comment: And do not put any code inside the constructor directly, instead, you should add a method called `ngOnInit()` which Angular calls once right after it creates the component. `ngOnInit(): void {....your initialization code here...}`

Comment: So inside my `navbar.component.ts` I put `console.log(this.dfServices.getSettings().title);` inside my `ngOnInit()` and I receive null in my console. This is after following your answer.

Comment: But if I put it in my dashboard component, it works just fine, just like you said it would. Weird that it doesn't work inside the navbar component though. Maybe just put the navbar html back in the `app.component.html` file rather than having it seperate.

Comment: It is not weird. It is because my answer was assuming you have all your other components inside/under your `AppComponent` and also there was a bug of a possible race condition but if it is not the case then I posted an update to the answer which will work even if you have your navbar HTML code outside `app.component.html` and will also solve the race condition.

Comment: Great! Thank you for taking the time to help me through this and actually explain the steps! Have a great evening and happy coding! I’ve accepted your answer as well!

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for an angular service. You should expose your shared data through a common service component that both the app component and navbar component share using injection.

Comment: Okay, so what's the difference between placing it in the component or a service other than technicality? IF I just copy and paste the code into a service from the component, won't it provide me the same results? Not trying to sound rude, just learn.

Comment: A service is *injectable*. You register a service with one of Angular's injectors so it can be injected into any of your components. (A component is *not* injectable and cannot be registered with the injector.) Also, a service registered with the `root` injector is a singleton, meaning its data is shared with *every* component. A component's data cannot be shared. Once the user navigates away from a component, its data is gone. For more information, check out the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: Good software design practice: separation of concerns. Keep your data model separate from your UI.

Comment: I have an example of a *very* simple service here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simpleservice-deborahk

Comment: Still results in `undefined`.

Comment: @MitchEvans can you share your updated code with the service which still results in `undefined`?

Comment: @mkhayata done! Hope it's not to terrible! still learning haha!

Comment: @MitchEvans you are not injecting the service into your component. First, inject the service into your `AppComponent` then in your `getSettings()` method do not subscribe, instead, return `this.afAuth.authState;` and do the subscription inside the `AppComponent`

Comment: @mkhayata okay so then `import { DefaultsService } from './defaults/defaults.service';` at the top of `app.component.ts` and then placing `private dfServices: DefaultsService` inside `constructor` is not injecting it?

Comment: @MitchEvans It is but I don't see that in your posted code, can you update your `AppComponent`?

Comment: @MitchEvans OK, your issue is an asynchronous race condition. I will post an answer with your updated code working.

Comment: @MitchEvans I've posted an answer with your code updated.